# dynamic string ng-repeat that define in text $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to define dynamic `ng-repeat` in $scope variable like this:

```
$scope.radioOptions =[{value:1,name:'radio1'},{value:2,name:'radio2'}];
$scope.item = {
    model: "radio", 
    radioOptions:'opt in radioOptions',
    optValue:'value',
    optLabel:'name'
}
```

and use it in html:

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="item.radioOptions">
      <input type="radio" id="{{$index}}" ng-value="item.optValue" name="{{item.model}}">
       <label for="{{$index}}">{{item.optLabel }}</label>
 </div>
```

But error me

> Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=item.radioOptions

Now, How to create dynamic `ng-repeat` with this specification?

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this in this way ? Can you not use `ng-repeat="ro in radioOptions" ?`

Comment: I can't use regular syntax because I want to use this ng-repeat to generate dynamic input radio

Comment: What do you call "Dynamic" input radio ? You can dynamically update `$scope.radioOptions`

Comment: have you tried this? - ng-repeat={{item.radioOptions}}

Comment: @Weedoze, I generate radio as dynamically

Comment: @RubenKarapetyan, error me with this syntax

Comment: Hmm.. I think I got your question.. the correct way to do this is creating a directive.

Comment: @developer033, Ok, Is there any way for this without directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to generate radio dynamically,

```
  $scope.radioOptions =[{value:1,name:'radio1'},{value:2,name:'radio2'}];

  $scope.item = {
      model: "radio", 
      radioOptions:$scope.radioOptions,
      optValue:'value',
      optLabel:'name'
  }
```

and in html:

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="option in item.radioOptions">
     <input type="radio" id="{{$index}}" ng-value="option[item.optValue]" name="{{option[item.model]}}">
     <label for="{{$index}}">{{option[item.optLabel]}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not my answer. my html is template and I want to repeat radio. but `option in item.radioOptions` is variable and changeable by user.

Comment: Can you please explain more regarding "html is template". In the answer above the user can change the radioOptions variable as it is a pointer and hence dynamic by nature.

Comment: I want to define input that user can type name of list variable.

Comment: please check my answer. I think this is not expensive

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with function that get name of array and then return array collection:

```
$scope.radioOptions =[{value:1,name:'radio1'},{value:2,name:'radio2'}];
$scope.item = {
    model: "radio", 
    radioOptions:'radioOptions',
    optValue:'value',
    optLabel:'name'
}

// get array collection by name
$scope.getCollection = function (name) {
        return $scope[name];
    };
```

and change html to:

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline" ng-repeat="opt in getCollection(item.radioOptions)">
      <input  type="radio" id="{{$index}}" ng-value="opt[item.optValue]" name="{{item.model}}">
      <label for="{{$index}}">{{opt[item.optLabel] }}</label>
</div>
```